# Python - How to create X amount of blank variables

Tags: python, variables, ascii

Just wondering how to create X number of blank variables with X being the length of a string entered by the user. I know how to calculate the length, just not how to create X amount of blank variables.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "blank variables"? Are you at all familiar with the built-in data types, particularly `list`?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using the variables to hold characters from the string... if so, have you looked into the way Python handles slicing? https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/strings.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not have one list that has length `X`?

```
lst = [None] * X
```

Or a `dict`:

```
namespace = dict.fromkeys(('varname%d'%i for i in range(X)), None)
namespace = {'varname%d' % i: None for i in range(X)}  # alternative
```

Generally, if you want to create names for variables dynamically, you should step back and ask yourself why.  How do you plan on using those variables?  You have no way of knowing if `varname1` is defined other than to inspect the globals or locals dictionary anyway (or litter your code with `NameError` exception handling).  Hopefully you can see that it is almost<sup>1</sup> always cleaner to use a dict or list in the first place.

<sup><sup>1</sup>I said "almost" because I'm sure somebody would try to come up with a scenario where this might be marginally useful -- but I sure can't think of anything right now...</sup>